# Ext.js - text fields losing focus while typing & become hidden by keyboard

Tags: extjs, textbox, iphone-softkeyboard

I made a web app using Ext.js & Sencha Cmd. Everything works well in the desktop view & almost everything works in the mobile view.... except for the text fields in the form panel. When I view on iPhone & focus on a text field, the keyboard appears & the page slides up, bringing the field into view. However, once I type 1 letter, it slides back down & the text fields are covered up by the keyboard, preventing the user from seeing what they are typing. Sometimes it jumps up & down but usually just stays down until I focus on another field. Everything I can find on line says this shouldn't be a problem with iOS devices but it clearly is for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What ExtJS version you are using?

Keep in mind that ExtJS are not actually for small screen devices, ExtJS5 is compatible with tablet.

Comment: I'm using EXTJS5. I haven't tried it on a tablet yet, I don't have one at work & I just figured it would probably do the same thing. Unfortunately, I really need it to work on iphones though (iphone 4 in particular.) Is there a way that I can maybe fake it & force the textbox to keep focus while I type?

Comment: As i said, ExtJs are not made for mobile. Sencha has it's designated product for it which is Sencha Touch,